# Context getting lost

Tags: javascript, scope

Why am I losing the context with setTimeout when I do not bind "this" in the call back.
In the code below you can see onTime gets called in 3 places.
Once from inside the class. Which works fine.
Once from outside the class. Which works fine.
Once when the timer triggers a call. "this" needs the bind method.
Is there a way to force the context without the use of bind in every call back?

```
var MyBaseClass = function () {
    "use strict";
    this._base = {};
    this._base.baseFunc = function () {
        console.log('baseFunc called')
    };
    return this._base;
};

var TestClass =  function () {
    "use strict";
    if (TestClass.prototype._singletonInstance) {
        return TestClass.prototype._singletonInstance;
    }
    TestClass.prototype._singletonInstance = this;
    this._timer = {};
    console.log('constructor')
};
TestClass.prototype = new MyBaseClass();        // Set prototype to MyBaseClass
TestClass.prototype.constructor = TestClass;   // Set constructor back to TestClass

TestClass.prototype.onTime = function () {
    "use strict";
    console.log('ontime called')
    console.log(this, "<--- why do i lose context")
    this.baseFunc()
}
TestClass.prototype.init = function () {
    "use strict";
    console.log('local')
    this.onTime()
    //this._timer = setTimeout(this.onTime.bind(this),500)// works
    this._timer = setTimeout(this.onTime, 500) // no work
};

var asdf = new TestClass()
asdf.init()
console.log('global')
asdf.onTime()
```

Comment: No. `setTimeout` executes the given function always in global context.

Comment: `this.onTime.apply(this)`?

Comment: @FrançoisWahl apply, call, bind are what I am trying to avoid. Basically I want a way in the I create the class to force its own context( if that makes sense ) I don't want to have to test everytime and validate that everything is as it should be.

Comment: @Bergi That is what I found.

Comment: @The_asMan: By design when an inner function is invoked, `this` in the inner function is not bound to the `this` variable of the outer function. A way to deal with this is to use one of the available invocation patterns such as `.apply()`, `var that = this`, `constructor invocation` or similar as required and set `this` to the expected context. I don't think there will be a choice. It's by design, good or bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that you only pass a function to setTimeout, not an object, so setTimeout could not possibly be aware of your desired context. The solution is to use a wrapping function to hold the context (dojo's hitch, known as bind in many other libs). This *is* the way to force context, I'm not sure why you're looking for something else. One option could be to bind once in a constructor, then you could pass the function around without worrying about context, like this :

`this.onTime = this.onTime.bind(this);
// now you can pass the function around
this._timer = setTimeout(this.onTime, 500) // works`

To clarify and to try and deal with your question about prototypes...

The reason why you would bind the function in the constructor (which is what I assumed your init function would be used as) as opposed to anywhere else, is that if you construct (using `new`) a second object, you want that object to be the context for the functions executed on it. You get this behaviour for free when executing the functions directly (`myObj.myFunc`) but care is needed when the functions are passed on (`setTimeout(myObj.myFunc, 50)` or `var callback = myObj.myFunc;`). This is the core problem you are experiencing and there are two strategies you can use :

### Bind when passing the function

This is basically the method you developed yourself, when passing your function to `setTimeout`, you bind it to your object. I'm still not sure I understand why you don't like this technique, but it is a valid pattern which is used by many libs etc.

```
setTimeout(myObj.myFunc.bind(myObj), 50);
```

### Bind when constructing the object

This is the soonest possible time you could bind - you cannot bind when setting the functions on the prototype, because the object has not been constructed yet, what would you bind to? With this technique, you can call setTimeout normally, safe in the knowledge that the function you are passing has been "prebound".

```
var myObjClass = function(){
    this.myFunc = this.myFunc.bind(this);
}
myObjClass.prototype.myFunc = function(){};
var myObj = new myObjClass();

setTimeout(myObj.myFunc);
```

Comment: No idea why this was downvoted it is the best one so far. Can you explain what you meant by bind once in the constructor.

Comment: @bfavaretto what do you believe is the difference between a function and a function reference in JS?

Comment: @The_asMan in my code sample, after the first line, you can call set timeout or anything else without binding again, because onTime is now a wrapper of the original, holding the context.

Comment: Will this apply with prototyping? Will take a look at this in an hour I have a meeting with a lunch plate that I just cant be late for.

Comment: Binding in the constructor was exactly what I was looking for. Are there and ramifications with this method? Obviously there will be more initial overhead with the prebinding, but then again that should lower the overhead since bind will never have to be called again.

Comment: not really, the only concern might be function overhead. As long as you only "prebind" functions that would definitely be bound at least once later on, then it's fine. To be clear, bind does not alter the original function it creates a new function, so each object will have its own separate function, meaning more functions overall depending on the number of objects. But this is no different to the number of functions with binding when passing, so I wouldn't worry.

Comment: JSHint doesn't complain about this method either so that's a bonus

Answer (score 0):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9FSzx/1/)

To keep context create a new method in setTimeout. You are passing method reference which has no context assocotions.

```
TestClass.prototype.init = function () {
    "use strict";
    console.log('local')
    this.onTime();
    var me = this; 
    //this._timer = setTimeout(this.onTime.bind(this),500)// works
    this._timer = setTimeout(function(){
        me.onTime();
        }, 500) 
};
```

Comment: @Bergi No it does work the use of a closure traps the context. But again this is extra code to force the context.

Comment: @The_asMan It's either closure or bind. There's no other way!

Comment: @bfavaretto there has to be another way like forced context on the function itself like function onTime(){ }.bind(this)

Comment: @The_asMan: Yeah, now it works with the closure. Yet in the original code (on which I commented) Sushil forgot `me = this` and used `this` inside the anonymous function, which was quite useless and obviously wrong